# UITesting command line argument options

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to write UITests for my company's app.  I came across several articles about passing command line arguments to my app, such as:

```
if CommandLine.arguments.contains("--uitesting-enrolled") {
    resetEnrolledState()
} else if CommandLine.arguments.contains("--uitesting-unenrolled") {
    resetUnenrolledState()
}
```

Within the `resetEnrolledState()` and `resetUnenrolledState()` methods, I set/unset `UserDefault` values, so that I know my environment has been properly configured.

Is there a better option than mixing my prod code with my test code?

Answer (score 3):

The only ways I know of involve mixing your production and test code, and this is by design.  [From Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH13-SW1):

> UI testing exercises your app's UI in the same way that users do without access to your app's internal methods, functions, and variables.

The best advice I can give is to try and put all of your test-centric code in a single place, and do as much in unit testing as possible.